# select each row in table and update column value

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to loop through each row in a table and update file from the file system. I am not sure this is efficient method of select and update at the the same time. Please let me know if there is any better way of doing this.

```
    using (SqlConnection oConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        oConnection.Open();

        using (SqlTransaction oTransaction = oConnection.BeginTransaction())
        {
            using (SqlCommand oCommand = oConnection.CreateCommand())
            {
                oCommand.Transaction = oTransaction;
                oCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                oCommand.CommandText = "SELECT d_id, doc_name, up_date, doc_path FROM Table1 where up_date between '2015/02/03' and '2015/12/30'";

                SqlDataReader reader = oCommand.ExecuteReader();

                try
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        string docPath = string.Format("C:\\{1}", reader["doc_path"].tostring());
                        int docId = Convert.ToInt32(reader["doc_id"]);
                        byte[] file;

                        using (var stream = new FileStream(docPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                        {
                            using (var reader1 = new BinaryReader(stream))
                            {
                                file = reader1.ReadBytes((int)stream.Length);
                            }
                        }

                        using (var sqlWrite = new SqlCommand("UPDATE INTO Table1 (doc_file) Values(@File) where doc_id = @docId", connectionString))
                        {
                            sqlWrite.Parameters.Add("@File", SqlDbType.VarBinary, file.Length).Value = file;
                            sqlWrite.Parameters.Add("@docId", SqlDbType.Int32).Value = docId;
                            sqlWrite.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    // Always call Close when done reading.
                    reader.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your update query is wrong. You need to provide identifier in it

Comment: And please refer to Code Review if you want suggestions on code improvement.

Comment: edited updated query. thanks.

Comment: Don't mix update and insert syntax. Use `UPDATE Table1 set doc_file = @File where doc_id = @docId`